# Get all values of HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, servlets

My page calls a servlet that return text (string) of HTML form and render it using `<h:outputText value="#{controller.htmlForm}" escape="false" />` and I want to get all values from that form to the controller. How can I achieve this?

The servlet will return something like this

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Page Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="/app/urlServlet">
           <input type="text" name="input1" >
           <input type="text" name="input2" >
           <input type="text" name="input3" >
           <input type="text" name="input4" >
       </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

My xhtml contains JSF tag like this

```
<h:outputText value="#{controller.htmlForm}" escape="false" />
<p:commandButton value="#{piece['submit']}" id="btnSubmit" action="#{controller.submit()}"/>
```

The controller variable **htmlForm** is used to put the HTML string from servlet. Now when the Submit button clicked I want to get the values from the form **myForm** in my controller.submit() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question cant be resolved using JSF as the HTML returned from the servlet is a plain HTML and not tied to any JSF controller. The solution can be done using jQuery alternative:

**1. jQuery submit()**

Using submit() method of jQyery will submit all input values within the form in query string format `input1=value1&input2=value2&input3=value3&input4=value4` using GET HTTP method.

```
    $("form[name=myForm]").submit();
```

**2. jQuery ajax request and serialize() method**

Using jQuery ajax request we can choose what HTTP method we want to use (GET / POST) and we can get the values of the form using serialize() method.

```
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : www.url.com,
        data : $("form[name=myForm]").serialize(),
        success : function(data) {
            // Process on success
        },
        error : function(error) {
            // Process on error
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `<h:inputText>` for your input fields and bind its value to a field in your Controller.java.

```
<h:inputText label="input1" value="#{controller.value1}" />
```

In your class, you have to define a String field "value1" with getter and setter.

[Look here for information about the tags you are allowed to put in `<h:inputText>` (e.g. style, tabindex or title)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/inputText.html)